# Jenkins timing out

Tags: jenkins, groovy, try-catch, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am working with Jenkins pipelines and I have this code:

```
 stages {
        stage('Stage1') {
            options {
                timeout(time: 1, unit: "MINUTES")
            }
            steps {
                    script {
sh'''
#!/bin/bash
set -eux pipefail

ssh user@server.com "
  ssh -p 50 user@localhost'\
    docker run --rm --name name\
     -e user=...\
     -e passwd=...\
     -v /location:/location2\
     -w location2\
     server2.com:6000/my-x-y:1.1\
     python script.py\
   '\
     "
    '''
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

When the connection inside the script is not being made the job will timeout but it will still go on and will be still marked as succeeded.
I get this message:

```
17:10:53  Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
17:10:53  Sending interrupt signal to process
```

After that the jobs moves to the next stage and the status is success.

So even though I am getting timeout the job is being marked as success.

I'd like to send notifications when this stage is not properly executed (I already have a notification.sh script for it).

Anyway I can get this job to be aborted when it gets the timeout?
Or any other way to go around this in order to warn users that this stage was not properly executed?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
try {
   timeout (time: 10, unit: 'SECONDS') {
   sh'''
      #!/bin/bash
      set -eux pipefail

      ssh user@server.com "
      ssh -p 50 user@localhost'\
       docker run --rm --name name\
        -e user=...\
        -e passwd=...\
        -v /location:/location2\
        -w location2\
        server2.com:6000/my-x-y:1.1\
        python script.py\
      '\
        "
    '''
   }
 }
 catch (error) {
     echo "Error: $error"
     def cause = error.getCauses()[0].getClass().toString()
     if(cause.contains("ExceededTimeout")) { // If you want handle timeout as a special case
        echo "This was a Timeout"
        // Do whatever you want
     }
}
```

Full Sample Pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('TimerTest') {
            steps {
                script {
                    
                    try {
                      timeout (time: 10, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                         echo "In timer"
                         sleep 15
                      }
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        echo "XXXX: $error"
                        def cause = error.getCauses()[0].getClass().toString()
                        println "$cause"
                        if(cause.contains("ExceededTimeout")) {
                           echo "This was a Timeout"
                           // Do what ever you want
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this, and it doesnt get into the catch as I cannot see message "error: ..." and neither "this was a time out". Why is this happening?

Comment: @fr0zt I have added a full working Pipeline, Please check whether that works.

Comment: I am getting this: 15:41:02  Error: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException
Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException getCauses. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature. I am not an adming, anyway we can try a different approach?

Comment: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException getCauses
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:265)

Comment: So this means upon timeout the execution is moving to the `catch` block. You need to approve the script inorder to run some Groovy there.

Comment: anyh other way we could do this with approval?

Comment: If you don't want to specifically check whether the error was caused by a timeout, just remove the lines after `echo "XXXX: $error"`

Comment: I'll try do get approvals and reply here in a few days. Thanks